# ConditionNot met on UpdateRelationships graph action

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I have a piece of program which automates application management for Microsoft Intune using graph api (beta version).

But, there is an a problem with [UpdateRelationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-mobileapp-updaterelationships?view=graph-rest-beta) action when I am trying to perform a call with empty array body to update supersedence list of application.

```cs
 await _graphServiceClient.DeviceAppManagement.MobileApps[lobApp.Id]
                        .UpdateRelationships(Array.Empty<MobileAppSupersedence>())
                        .Request()
                        .PostAsync();
```

For applications which have assignments, sometimes, I receive response **ConditionNotMet** like is this example

```
Code: ConditionNotMet Message: { "_version": 3, "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 59853b92-273a-4c4a-b1b7-3d0accb74e09 - Url: https://fef.amsua0602.manage.microsoft.com/AppLifecycle_2402/StatelessAppMetadataFEService/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps('3a67578e-7f85-4af0-bf46-ab14c216e059')/microsoft.management.services.api.updateRelationships?api-version=5023-11-15", "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "", "RetryAfter": null, "ErrorSourceService": "", "HttpHeaders": "{}" } Inner error: AdditionalData: date: 2024-02-14T08:44:17 request-id: 59853b92-273a-4c4a-b1b7-3d0accb74e09 client-request-id: 59853b92-273a-4c4a-b1b7-3d0accb74e09 ClientRequestId: 59853b92-273a-4c4a-b1b7-3d0accb74e09
```

Maybe, there is some internal status or something else that prevent application to be updated. Could someone help with that?

I checked request which is used by Intune UI for updating supersedence list for application and it is a similar to request which is formed by graph api sdk.